# Lua cURL how to get json response?

Tags: curl, lua

I use such lua code for sending json post data:

```
local cURL = require("cURL")
local request = cURL.easy{
   url        = "http://myurl",
   post       = true,
   httpheader = { "Content-Type: application/json"; },
   postfields = jsonString,
   timeout = 1
}

request:perform()
```

How to get response json string?

Comment: Haven't used `lua-curl`, but 3 minutes of reading the [manual](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3) suggests adding a `writefunction` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to get json response from the server is:

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local cjson = require("cjson")
local requesrString = "http://hostname/path?params"
local body, code = http.request(requesrString)
local jsonDict = cjson.decode(body)
```

Comment: This language is terrible that it depends on the other community packages.